# 1000baseT to 10/100 adapter needs

Tags: ethernet

I'm looking for insight/help with a problem I'm having.

I have a camera that specifically needs a 1000baseT connection in order to communicate over gigabit. The access points we use with the cameras are limited to 10/100 (Ubiquiti Picostation M2). The camera cannot use anything other than its stated spec.

Is there a chip or converter that currently exists that could do this? Where would I need to begin looking if it doesn't?

(there is no need to have the data moving this fast wirelessly.  The 1000baseT is required by the NIC on the camera just to have a successful handshake.  Small four port switches are out of the equation primarily due to size.  We're looking for a small chipset/ready made board or adapter that might help with this)

Comment: If a small switch is out "due to size", any *media converter* is too as they're all much bigger than most 4 port switches. That in mind, yes, there are numerous switch chips on the market capable of doing what you want (hint: that's what's inside those small switches) $30 off-the-shelf switch vs. $100k (min) to engineer your own handful of "bullet" in-line converters.

Comment: Ricky Bean- I've looked at the possibility of using a solution like that (chip), but it's outside of where I  currently am on the learning train.  Would the below chip be adequate (http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/us/en/micrel-ksz9031-series-ethernet-transceiver/3904).  If so, is it a simple matter of lining up the appropriate legs of the chip for data in and out?

Comment: That's only a PHY (the chip for a NIC.) I'm pretty sure it wouldn't work cross linking two of them. What you want is the basis for a switch. (there are too many choices to list. And product recommendations are off-topic.) As I said, unless you're making thousands of them, it's not cost effective.

Comment: Cross linking two phys running at the same speed might work. Cross linking two phys running at different speeds definately won't.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason that the camera requires that bandwidth, and you may (probably will) have problems if you restrict the speed on the path.

You can't directly convert 1000BASE-T to 100BASE-TX. You could try a small gigabit ethernet switch between the camera and the rest of the network.

Specific product recommendations are off-topic on this forum.

Comment: Perhaps, but the designers could simply have been boneheads and locked it to gig only. (or it's an optical interface; he didn't name the camera)

Comment: I agree about the bonehead designers (having worked around things that the company bought and depends on), but that is a reason, too. Negotiation is required by the 1000BASE-T standard. and it's built into just about every chipset out there. The designers probably had to go out of their way to disable it. I would certainly disable it if my product is crippled, or some features rendered useless, running at 100BASE-TX, hence my warning. I'm guessing the Wi-Fi throughput will top out at 30 Mbps if the WAPs' wired ports are limited to 10/100 Mbps. It sounds like a bad idea all the way around.

Comment: Actually, (as one who deals with sort of stuff) it's not hard at all -- and in fact, I've had to alter broadcom's SDK to *allow* 10/100 on a gig port. (a small error in their mac setup prevents tri-mode mac's from dropping to 10 or 100.)

Comment: The camera is a Red Dragon.  The port on the side of it is simple a Gig-E port with a  specification listed in the manual as requiring 1000baseT for the camera to even communicate.  If the camera is plugged in to a 10/100 device, the hand shake doesn't occur.  I've even written the manufacturer requesting further information, hoping for the possibility of using 100baseT and was told that is out of the question.

Comment: @Shame0360, that would seem to suggest that using it on a slower speed network will produce unacceptable results. It may require something faster than 100 Mb, and slowing it down on the network will cause problems. You need to ask the manufacturer how it will perform if you do connect it to a network that steps down the bandwidth to 100BASE-TX or 802.11 speeds. This is the sort of thing you need to take into account before you buy something. It seems to have 9X more pixels than HD, and that can take a lot of bandwidth to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

To interface between different speeds requires a device that can accept complete frames into a buffer and retransmit them at the changed speed. That pretty much means a switch.

Custom designing a switch in the form factor you want will not be a cheap option. EEs at the skill level to successfully build a reliable gigabit Ethernet implementation don't come cheap.

I think your best option is probably to change to a different wireless access point.